# Problems using Traefik reverse proxy in front of a Caddy proxy

Tags: docker, ssl, traefik, caddy

We have a Docker project that uses Caddy as the TLS providing reverse proxy to a PHP container, which also provides HTTP/3 & Mercure protocol support, and this all works fine if exposing the ports of the Caddy container directly, however we're introducing a Traefik proxy so that we can use the same ports (80/443) for all local dev environments, which works fine for other projects, however trying to put this in front of the Caddy container doesn't work.

I've tried setting this up as a TCP router with passthrough configured, and Traefik sets up the router & service, as can be seen in the web console, however I get an SSL error in the browser when attempting to access the page.

Here is the Docker compose labels…

```yaml
services:
  caddy:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: api_platform_caddy
    depends_on:
      php:
        condition: service_started
    labels:
      traefik.docker.network: traefik
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.tcp.routers.api-v2-caddy.rule: HostSNI(`show.api.localhost`)
      traefik.tcp.routers.api-v2-caddy.tls: "true"
      traefik.tcp.routers.api-v2-caddy.tls.passthrough: "true"
      traefik.tcp.services.api-v2-caddy.loadbalancer.server.port: "443"
      traefik.udp.routers.api-v2-caddy.entrypoints: http3
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - show.api.local
      traefik: ~
    # Ports allow direct access
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: "8081"
        protocol: tcp
      - target: 443
        published: "443"
        protocol: udp
      - target: 443
        published: "8443"
        protocol: tcp
    restart: unless-stopped
```

And here's the Traefik proxy config…

```yaml
# Docker configuration backend
providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/dynamic_config
    watch: true

# API and dashboard configuration
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ':80'
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          # Redirect all http requests to https
          to: https
  https:
    address: ':443'
  http3:
    address: ':443/udp'

log:
  level: DEBUG
  format: json
```

I've also seen posts asking for openssl output, so here's what I have on that, although I don't really understand what this is telling me…

```
$ openssl s_client -connect show.api.localhost:443 -servername show.api.localhost -msg
CONNECTED(00000003)
>>> TLS 1.0, RecordHeader [length 0005]
    16 03 01 01 47
>>> TLS 1.3, Handshake [length 0147], ClientHello
    01 00 01 43 03 03 a5 cf 7a de f2 f1 fc 22 62 8e
    7c 41 75 6e bf c2 83 1d 85 cc b8 6d 3b c6 6f 85
    25 8b 62 d6 e6 31 20 64 1c 1a 62 1a 5f 64 b9 1c
    73 14 ea 6a f3 d9 e0 f5 68 d7 17 c6 1d 51 de 01
    1f 51 b2 74 67 32 41 00 3e 13 02 13 03 13 01 c0
    2c c0 30 00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa c0 2b c0 2f 00
    9e c0 24 c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27 00 67 c0 0a c0
    14 00 39 c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d 00 9c 00 3d 00
    3c 00 35 00 2f 00 ff 01 00 00 bc 00 00 00 23 00
    21 00 00 1e 73 68 6f 77 2e 61 70 69 2e 67 6f 6f
    64 63 72 6d 2e 64 65 76 2e 6c 6f 63 61 6c 68 6f
    73 74 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 16 00 14
    00 1d 00 17 00 1e 00 19 00 18 01 00 01 01 01 02
    01 03 01 04 00 23 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 17 00 00
    00 0d 00 2a 00 28 04 03 05 03 06 03 08 07 08 08
    08 09 08 0a 08 0b 08 04 08 05 08 06 04 01 05 01
    06 01 03 03 03 01 03 02 04 02 05 02 06 02 00 2b
    00 05 04 03 04 03 03 00 2d 00 02 01 01 00 33 00
    26 00 24 00 1d 00 20 b3 59 4e 4f a6 1e 24 b4 13
    de 49 a3 0a f5 90 3d bc f5 93 68 5d be 31 bd 2a
    f9 b5 c2 1e d7 94 08
<<< TLS 1.2, RecordHeader [length 0005]
    15 03 03 00 02
<<< TLS 1.3, Alert [length 0002], fatal internal_error
    02 50
40019F0B02000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 332 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.  And answers provided if you need more info.

Thanks in advance.